# what is the scope of usefulness of gae nginx logs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to debug a 502 error that I'm getting with a deployed GCP app.  I was perusing the associated logs and I came across the nginx logs for the GAE.  It appears to log that 502 errors occurred, along with symptom information like latency in seconds.  For example, the following logs show that a 502 error occurred, along with the associated latency (over 4 minutes in this case):

https://github.com/git-it-2020/random/blob/master/gae_nginx-request%20logs.json

However, at a glance, I'm not able to infer root cause info from these logs?  Is this expected?  Ie the nginx logs only record that a 502 occurred but aren't really useful for inferring root cause info?

Comment: Stackdriver does not record your application internal behavior unless you do that explicitly. App Engine logs the request, and the returned status. You will need to use traditional debugging techniques to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this post in Serverfault related to the  [502](https://serverfault.com/questions/951189/seeing-502-on-google-app-engine), is very well explained.

Here you can find all the [logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?resource=gae_app&_ga=2.228567701.-966000341.1566204075&_gac=1.36889492.1579706128.EAIaIQobChMI38a65K2X5wIVB_hRCh2RmARVEAAYASAAEgIqwfD_BwE) for your app.

If you are working in an flexible environment you can [enable the debug](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/instances/enable-debug).